# HQL Query that returns column of type string

Tags: c#-4.0, hql, nhibernate-criteria

how to retrieve a single column's value of type string using HQL.
I tried the following way but is not working.

```
    public virtual string GetCityById(int Id)
    {
        using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                var queryString = string.Format("SELECT C.CityName FROM {0} AS C WHERE Id=:Id", typeof(T));
                return session.CreateQuery(queryString).SetInt32("Id", Id).ToString(); <--Also tried with .SetParameter("Id",Id)
            }
        }
    }
```

Expected Output is:

> NEWYORK

Actual Output is:

> Select Name FROM FNHHelper.Entites.Cities WHERE Id=:Id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning the String representation of the query. You just need to execute the query, and return its unique result:

```
session.CreateQuery(queryString).SetInt32("Id", Id).UniqueResult();
```

(assuming the method name is the same as in the Java version).